# how to add subtitle to mp4 in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avmutablecomposition, video-watermarking

i already know that i should use AVFoundationto get the CGContextRef from .mp4 file;

and use like :

```
CATextLayer *subtitle1Text = [[CATextLayer alloc] init];
[subtitle1Text setFont:@"Helvetica-Bold"];
[subtitle1Text setFontSize:36];
[subtitle1Text setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, 400)];
[subtitle1Text setString:[self.subtitles objectAtIndex:idx]];
[subtitle1Text setAlignmentMode:kCAAlignmentCenter];
[subtitle1Text setForegroundColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];

[subtitle1Text drawInContext:context];
```

to make subtitles;

now the question is how can i get CGContextRef from .mp4 file?

i mean i've got the url of .mp4 file, but how can i add CATextLayer in the mp4?

Comment: Have you checked this tutorial?
http://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos

Comment: In this tutorial everything is mentioned,

Comment: i've found http://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos,   and now i'm trying to read it,but it's kind of difficult.....but think you any way @aBilal17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use AVFoundation framework in order to add text on video you can have a look into the following link for more detail. You have add the text layer on video layer and then have to export it.

[AVMutableComposition](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMutableComposition_Class/index.html)

Have a look into bellow sample code there is a way to add watermark you can create subtitles by changing few properties like start time and end time.

[AVSimpleEditoriOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVSimpleEditoriOS/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012797)